# issues with os.system() not generating output

Tags: python, os.system

When I run the program I get everything up to `q` outputted as it should be, but the .mafft that should be created by `q` is coming back empty. Edit: I forgot to ask the actual question. What am I doing wrong here? Is it some syntax I am unaware of?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import math

data = sys.argv[2]
b = sys.argv[1]

bfile = open(b, "r")
for barcode in bfile:
        barcode = barcode.strip()
        print "barcode: %s" %barcode
        outfname = "%s.%s.fasta" % (data, barcode)
        print outfname
        outf = open(outfname,"w")
        handle = open(data, "r")
        for line in handle:
                linearr = line.split()
                sid = linearr[0]
                seq = linearr[1]
                potential_barcode = seq[0:len(barcode)]
                if potential_barcode == barcode:
                        outseq = line.replace(potential_barcode, "", 1)
                        newseq = outseq.split(' ',1)[-1].strip()
                        sys.stdout.write(newseq)
                        outf.write(">%s\n%s\n" % (sid,newseq))
        gamma = outfname + ".mafft"
        delta = gamma + ".stock"

        q =  "mafft %s > %s" % (outfname, gamma)
        os.system(q)

        qq = "fasta_to_stockholm %s > %s" % (gamma, delta)
        os.system(qq)

        qqq = "quicktree -out m %s" % (delta)
        os.system(qqq)

        handle.close()
        outf.close()
bfile.close()
```

Comment: Use subprocess and redirect to a file object

Comment: @PadraicCunningham   So instead of os.system() use subprocess()?

Comment: No.  [Read the manual](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: It is not  a literal swap, the code will be different but it is the correct way to do it

Comment: Is there a way to still use os.system? I'm reading the manual @Kevin and I don't understand how to substitute it.

Comment: If the .mafft is being created, then the shell is running.   I don't think its an issue with `os.system` but with your mafft program.  Did you check the return code from `os.system()`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements specifically 17.1.4.3

Comment: I have checked the mafft program, it returns what it should. What do you mean by return code (beginner here doesn't recognize that terminology)? @cdarke

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I changed the code to `q = "mafft %s >>%s" % (outfname, gamma)
subprocess.call(q, shell = True)`
and I am still getting an empty file for my .mafft file.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me this program is outputting to stderr instead of stdout.

Comment: Programs by convention return zero on success and some other number on error.  `retn = os.system(q)` will give that number, but it could be an error code from the shell, if for example it cannot find the program.  See the doc.

Comment: @cdarke retn returned a zero.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham As in the one you just gave me? I am getting check_call is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with using `os.system()` instead of `subprocess`.
The problem is that you are not closing the `outfname` file before running the program.  Move the closes to **before** the `os.system()` call:

```
    handle.close()
    outf.close()

    gamma = outfname + ".mafft"
    delta = gamma + ".stock"

    q =  "mafft %s > %s" % (outfname, gamma)
    os.system(q)
```

The input file to `mafft` (`outfname`) is empty because the buffers have not been flushed, you are "suffering from buffering".

I would consider what everyone has said about using `subprocess`, but *after* you get this working!  Only change one thing at a time!

Comment: The changes you suggested are working perfectly. I have run into a bit of a snag with one of the stockholm translations but I just fixed it by clearing the old files. Thank you!